# Base constructor in base class instead of derived class in C#

Tags: c#, constructor, abstract-class

I'm learning how to properly apply OO principles in C#. I came across a little problem and I can't figure out how to solve it. I run into the following problem:

The current situation:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    protected Foo()
    {
        //does nothing
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public BarX ( int a, int b, int c) : base()
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public doStuff()
    {
        //does stuff
    }
}

public class BarY : Foo
{
    public Bar( int a, int b, int c) : base()
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public doStuff()
    {
        //does stuff
    }
}
```

The point is that I hafe different types of `Foo`. In this case it would be circles and rectangles. I want them to have the same constructors as each type has the same attributes. They only have a different `doStuff()` method. I have tried many combinations but every time I try to move the arguments to the base class's constructor it tells me that 'some class does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments' (or 3 arguments) depending how I move around my code.

My question is how I can move the assignment of a, b and c's values to the abstract class's constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    protected Foo(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public abstract void doStuff();
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar(int a, int b, int c) : base(a, b, c)
    {
    }

    public override void doStuff()
    {
        //does stuff
    }
}


public class BarY : Foo
{
    public BarY(int a, int b, int c) : base(a, b, c)
    {
    }

    public override void doStuff()
    {
        //does stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured it out :) I need to add the parameters in the base class and I need to add them in the chaining in de derived class: `BarX(int a, int b, int c) : base( a,b,c) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

That's because `BarY` and `BarX` are calling a default constructor (`base()`) which doesn't exist in your base class when you only have a parameterised constructor.  You need to pass the arguments through as well (`base(a, b, c)`):

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    protected Foo(int a, int b, int c) 
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public abstract void doStuff();
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public BarX (int a, int b, int c) : base(a, b, c)
    {

    }

    public override void doStuff()
    {
        //does stuff
    }
}

public class BarY : Foo
{
    public Bar(int a, int b, int c) : base(a, b, c)
    {

    }

    public override void doStuff()
    {
        //does stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Daniel Hilgarth was sooner so I marked his solution as answer. I still +1'ed you for the effort and the correct answer :)